# use timeit function to compare calculation time between iteration & vectorized function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timeit

I want to see if vectorized function calculates faster than iteration based on the same python pandas series. But the %%timeit -n part doesn't seem to work? Can anyone help?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,100))

import timeit 

# using iteration

%%timeit -n 100
summary = 0
for item in s:
    summary+=item

# versus the vectorized function 

%%timeit -n 100
summary = np.sum(s)
```

Comment: Are you running this in an IPython terminal or as a script? If it's the latter, that won't work. Something like "%timeit" is called a magic function that specifically works in IPython (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html)

Comment: Also, no need to `import timeit` and for single lines you can do `%timeit -n 100
summary = np.sum(s)`.  And finally, you'll need to make `s` bigger to see the advantage of the vectorized function.

Comment: I was running this in IPython. What is strange is that sometimes when I ran it  (%%timeit)  it worked but next time it didn't. I didn't change any code at all between different attempts. Could this be the issue with the cloud server? Anyone encountered similar issue before?